# Command line processing sequence in Swift4

Tags: swift

I'm new to Swift programming and I need some help to understand how Swift process the command lines

I'm using Xcode 11.2, Swift4, IOS13 and macOS Catalina

```
@IBAction func nextStep(_ sender: Any) {
    var urlR : String = ""

    self.buttonNext.isEnabled = false
    self.buttonNext.setTitle("Loading...", for: .normal)

    let storage = Storage.storage().reference()
    let imagesFolder = storage.child("images")
    let imagesFile = imagesFolder.child("\(imageID).jpg")

    print("Step 1 - Start")
    //Recover image
    if let imgRecovered = image.image {
        if let imgData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imgRecovered, 0.1) {
            imagesFile.putData(imgData, metadata: nil) { (metaData, error) in
                if error == nil {
                    //Download URL
                   imagesFile.downloadURL { (url, error) in
                        print("Step 2 \(url?.absoluteString) - End of print")
                        self.urlR = url!.absoluteString
                    }
                    // END Download URL

                    print("Step 3 \(self.urlR) - end of print")

                    print("Step 4 - Save Sucess")
                    self.buttonNext.isEnabled = true
                    self.buttonNext.setTitle("Próximo", for: .normal)

                    print("Step 5 - Perform Segue")
                    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "UserSelectionSegue", sender: self.urlRecebida)


                } else {
                    print("Step 6 - Upload error")
                    self.buttonNext.isEnabled = true
                    self.buttonNext.setTitle("Next", for: .normal)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've added some print message to understand the command line sequence and I'd expect the messages to be shown in the following order:
* Step 1
* Step 2
* Step 3
* Step 4
* Step 5
* (or Step 6 instead all of the above in case of errors).

But, the output I get is 
* Step 1
* Step 3
* Step 4
* Step 5
* Step 2

Why step 2 is the latest to be shown? What would I need to do to have it processed after Step 1?

Thanks for the help

Comment: imagesFile.downloadURL  is a so called asynchronous call which will be executed on another thread. That’s why 2 is coming latest.

Comment: Thanks Chris. Would tou know what should i add to my code to make sure the downloadurl call is processed in the right order? In my case i need the information coming from that call to proceed with the segue.

Comment: http://www.programmingios.net/what-asynchronous-means/

Comment: Nice article Matt! Worth reading for people that are new to Swift!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should solve it (just put everything in the closure)

```
@IBAction func nextStep(_ sender: Any) {
var urlR : String = ""

self.buttonNext.isEnabled = false
self.buttonNext.setTitle("Loading...", for: .normal)

let storage = Storage.storage().reference()
let imagesFolder = storage.child("images")
let imagesFile = imagesFolder.child("\(imageID).jpg")

print("Step 1 - Start")
//Recover image
if let imgRecovered = image.image {
    if let imgData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imgRecovered, 0.1) {
        imagesFile.putData(imgData, metadata: nil) { (metaData, error) in
            if error == nil {
                //Download URL
               imagesFile.downloadURL { (url, error) in
                    print("Step 2 \(url?.absoluteString) - End of print")
                    self.urlR = url!.absoluteString

                // END Download URL

                print("Step 3 \(self.urlR) - end of print")

                print("Step 4 - Save Sucess")
                self.buttonNext.isEnabled = true
                self.buttonNext.setTitle("Próximo", for: .normal)

                print("Step 5 - Perform Segue")
                self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "UserSelectionSegue", sender: self.urlRecebida)


            } else {
                print("Step 6 - Upload error")
                self.buttonNext.isEnabled = true
                self.buttonNext.setTitle("Next", for: .normal)
            }
        }
      }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help Chris!

Comment: You are welcome. Please upvote my answer - that would help me

Comment: Done :-) The only thing is that, even though clicking "this answer is usefull", it still shows 0... Thanks